# active record find returning #<Enumerator: ...>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

Rails `5.x`

Model School :

```
class School           
     has_many: students

   def all_students
    students.active + students.inactive 
   end 

end
```

and student model

```
class Student
 scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
 scope :active, -> { where(active: false) }
end
```

and this

```
 my_school = School.find(1)
 my_school.students.find(student_id) #returns `#<Enumerator: ...>`
```

PS: I can fix this changing `my_school.students.find(some_id)` but I can't skip the `all_students` method.

Comment: Is there any inactive scope in your student model?

Comment: no inactive scope @PalashBera